# How to include duo partner audio on my twitch stream from Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, fortnite-battle-royale, streaming, twitch

I'm trying to setup my son's Xbox One to stream on Twitch (Fortnite) and it mostly seems to be working. He can stream and with his headset you can hear his audio. What he can't figure out and I am struggling to find something instructive about is how he can include his Duo or Squad partners audio to come thru on his stream. He has invited people to his party, did co-stream invites and he is still only getting videos with his audio. Appreciate any insight from Xbox One streamers who know how to get this working. Thanks

Comment: Did the other players in the party select the option (in the party menu) to allow their audio to be part of the stream?

Comment: Hi Kevin, What program are you using to livestream?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can actually include in-game chat audio in the stream, but in the party there is a box that the others have to tick called share audio with stream

Answer (score 0):

On xbox there is a privacy feature when recording/streaming that you are unable to record/steam in game chat. On xbox party chat, people in the party have the option to include their audio. The only workaround for this is to buy a capture card and stream the gameplay to a pc, then stream that gameplay to twitch. This is a big hassle that has made me rethink my choice of buying xbox.